# How to detect if ssh keys are password protected?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Is it possible to detect just from the pub part of the ssh key if the key is password protected?

Comment: @Keyser's edit: are you sure that's what he ment? Could he not be refering to [this definition of password-less](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/25/how-to-set-up-a-password-less-ssh-login/)?

Comment: @Joost That's password-less logins, and he was asking about the actual keys. But you did make me a little uncertain. I'll let OP clear it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only the private key gets encrypted, the public part is not affected at all. Even if the public key contained information about the encryption status of the private key this would not be reliable - the private key can be decrypted and encrypted with a new password at any time.